# C# .NET 4.0 - windows deployment for multiple applications

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 C# windows applications within a single solution file in .NET 4.0 platform. In a single setup file, I need to first install 1st windows application and after its completion, in a background thread of first application I need to install the second application.

Please guide me on the way to do this.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If its the same solution then a single setup solution would install both.

Comment: yeah, but i dont want both application to be shown to be user. I need the user to install only 1st app and the second app needs to be installed at the background. please help!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding Custom Actions to your setup project. For details please have a look on this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

The idea is to add two different setup projects for both applications. Say we have setup1 and setup2 and setup1 should be finished before setup2. Build setup2 and in "Application Folder" of setup1 add files of setup2 (setup2.msi and setup.exe). Now in the Custom Actions of setup1, assign setup.exe under Commit folder from "Application Folder" (this setup.exe is actually of setup2). To add a custom action right click in the setup1 project in solution explorer and select View -> Custom Actions.

Adding an exe to Custom Actions under Commit means that the exe will run when the setup will finish the installation.

Comment: please explain the custom actions since, the second application need to be installed without the user knowledge.

Comment: Please explain why the user shall not see it. Otherwise I would like to downrate the question.

Comment: since we have contextmenu as 2nd application. There is no need to show the contextmenu application in our app. so we thought of hiding it.

Comment: Dear hamad, Thanks dude! I tried it! but 1 doubt, which setup i need to run whether setup1 or setup2?

Comment: In above case which I explained, it will be setup1.

Comment: what my app does is, we are creating messenger application as setup1 and once it is installed, contextmenu application as setup2 has to be installed but as a background thread?

Comment: i tried whatever you told, in that, messenger application is installed and i placed the exe of the contextmenu in commit tab but it is not installing..

Comment: contextmenu app is not installing automatically after messenger app

Comment: i have created primary output for both and added contextmenu.exe in appfolder of ims and had set the setup.exe of contextmenu in ims custom actions commit.

Comment: i need to build both the setup right? after running the setup of ims, contextmenu is not installed automatically!

Comment: k dude, i have another query? shall i

Comment: You said "it shows, a windows installer popup while installing ims!", what message is there in the popup? if another query is not related to this question, please post another question.

Comment: There should be something written on the popup.

Comment: @hamad You get +1.  "An A for effort".