# Installation setup in Visual Studio 2010 more than one project output

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

Is it possible to create installation package of two or more installation in visual studio 2010?When installation of the first exe is complete the it will install second exe.

Comment: Same question was posted yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889096/c-sharp-net-4-0-windows-deployment-for-multiple-applications/9889257#9889257

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the output from both your projects, that should allow you to achieve what you are trying to do I presume.

Right click on your setup project : `Add` -> `Project output`

Comment: Project output is fine. See i have Setup1 coming from completely different project solution which is exe and Setup 2 is the exe of the current project.I want setup1 one should install first and as soon as installation is complete Setup2 should get start install.

Comment: Oh ok, you are tryin to link both, without them having a direct relation. Hum, ive seen somewhere some kind of scripting/commands you can use with the installers, but i've got no idea of how to use them.